# Yesod Database.Persist.ODBC integration

Tags: haskell, odbc, yesod

How can we use `Yesod` with `persistent-odbc`? For instance the [following code](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) is for using Yesod with Sqlite:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns               #-}
import Yesod
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)
import Control.Monad.Logger (runStderrLoggingT)

-- Define our entities as usual
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    firstName String
    lastName String
    age Int
    deriving Show
|]

-- We keep our connection pool in the foundation. At program initialization, we
-- create our initial pool, and each time we need to perform an action we check
-- out a single connection from the pool.
data PersistTest = PersistTest ConnectionPool

-- We'll create a single route, to access a person. It's a very common
-- occurrence to use an Id type in routes.
mkYesod "PersistTest" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
/person/#PersonId PersonR GET
|]

-- Nothing special here
instance Yesod PersistTest

-- Now we need to define a YesodPersist instance, which will keep track of
-- which backend we're using and how to run an action.
instance YesodPersist PersistTest where
    type YesodPersistBackend PersistTest = SqlBackend

    runDB action = do
        PersistTest pool <- getYesod
        runSqlPool action pool

-- List all people in the database
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    people <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc PersonAge]
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <ul>
                $forall Entity personid person <- people
                    <li>
                        <a href=@{PersonR personid}>#{personFirstName person}
        |]

-- We'll just return the show value of a person, or a 404 if the Person doesn't
-- exist.
getPersonR :: PersonId -> Handler String
getPersonR personId = do
    person <- runDB $ get404 personId
    return $ show person

openConnectionCount :: Int
openConnectionCount = 10

main :: IO ()
main = runStderrLoggingT $ withSqlitePool "test.db3" openConnectionCount $ \pool -> liftIO $ do
    runResourceT $ flip runSqlPool pool $ do
        runMigration migrateAll
        insert $ Person "Michael" "Snoyman" 26
    warp 3000 $ PersistTest pool
```

How would it be like if instead of `Database.Persist.Sqlite` we used `Database.Persist.ODBC`?

Comment: See the example here: https://github.com/gbwey/persistent-odbc/blob/master/examples/TestODBC.hs . But try avoiding ODBC if you have better interfaces.

Comment: @Sibi I am trying to use `mysql + Yesod + Windows`, and the only way I got was through ODBC... Why should I avoid it at all?

Comment: @Sibi By the way, I have already seen the examples, but I didn't see an integration with Yesod there, for instance, implementing YesodPersist

Comment: It's just a library. There is no need for special integration needed with Yesod. You can simply plug-in and use it. I feel that `persistent-sqlite` is much better maintained by the community that the ODBC interface.

Comment: @Sibi I would like to see an example

Comment: I don't use ODBC or Windows, but I don't see why you couldn't just use `persistent-mysql`.

Comment: @MaxGabriel Because on windows 8+ it doesn't compile. I don't use windows at all, but unfortunally I will need to instal the server on Windows.

Comment: Hm, maybe file an issue about persistent-MySQL not compiling?